# checkbox to string conversion

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I have a page that contains diff properties with checkboxes.and I have another page that contains the summary of the above page. That means If I check the in the first page its has to reflect the relavent field details in the summary page.But as the variable type in pojo is boolean its showing as true of false.I unable to get the fields name.Im using HTML front end and java. Please help me on how to do it.

In pojo the variable is boolean. Im fetching that variable in the next summary page. I need that to be name of the variable not true of false. hope im clear

Comment: Show some code of setting and getting values from checkbox

Comment: Replace `variables.get("name")` by `variables.get("name") ? "name" : ""` or so?

Comment: This is the html row:
<tr>

  <td width="10%"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td width='10%' nowrap align="left"><input id="isFedMarried"
   jwcid="@Checkbox" selected='ognl:ocersMSSVisit.taxWith.fedMarried' /><label class='leftAlign' jwcid='@vitech:Label'
   for="pid" labelOverride="Married" style="vertical-align: top;"/></td>

 </tr>

Pojo:

public boolean isFedMarried() {
  return fedMarried;
 }
 public void setFedMarried(boolean fedMarried) {
  this.fedMarried = fedMarried;
 }
calling in this page

Comment: calling in this page...<td width='25%'><input id="idFedMarried" jwcid='@vitech:DisplayField' entityAttribute="ognl:als.PERSON.V_NAME"
   
   value='ognl:ocersMSSVisit.taxWith.fedMarried' /></td>

Answer (score 0):

You can add the string you want to properties, evaluate your boolean, get the message you want from properties according to the boolean value:

```
public String getLabel(){ if(isMarried) return messages.get(marriedPropertyMessage);}
```